How to prevent creating a new branch of a certain branch
We have these branches in Azure DevOps:
Master <--> development
When we want to do changes we have to make a new branch of the development branch.
Then do our changes, push it for review to the development branch and after approval merge it to the master branch.
We have some projects that do not have a development branch so it happens I create a new branch from the master.
This can give problems if the development is ahead of the master.
Is it possible to set a policy or permission so that you cannot create a new branch from, in this case, the master?
It would then be great if Visual Studio would disallow it.

Thank you for all suggestions/help.
After reading it wouldn't be possible, I renamed my local master to master_do_not_branch. That will teach me.... :-D

There is no any option to limit users cannot create branches based on a particular branch.
For your case, you can consider following the configurations like as below:

Go to Project Settings > Teams to create a team (e.g., Developers), and add all the developers of into this team in the project.


Go back to the repository to set the Branch policies, Branch security and Lock of the default branch (master or main).


Enable the following policies on the default branch (master in your case).

Require a minimum number of reviewers
Automatically included reviewers: Add yourself as the required automatically included reviewer.



Lock the default branch.


On the security hub of the default branch, ensure the permission "Remove others' locks" is "Deny" or "Not set" for the Developers team.


Create the development branch based on the default branch. Inform the developers that they should make changes on the development branch, or create their temporary branches based on the development branch and merge changes from the temporary into development branch. Then create PR for merging changes from development branch into the default branch.



With above configurations:

Due to the Branch policies, by default, all users cannot directly push new changes to the default branch. The developers need to create PR for merging changes from another branch into the default branch. Before the PR can be completed, it must get approved by the user who is the required approvers.


Due to the default branch is locked, the developers cannot complete the PR even if all the approvals and checks get passed on the PR. Only the user who locked the default branch can complete the PR. So, after you approved the PR, you can decide whether to complete the PR, or wait the developers to ask you to help to complete the PR.



When the developers make changes in the local repository, if they mistakenly make changes on the local default branch (master in your case) or other wrong branches, as @Daniel Mann suggested, you can inform the developers merge or cherry-pick the changes into the local development branch, then push the changes from local development branch to the remote development branch. And then create a PR for merging the changes from remote development branch into the remote default branch.


No. That's not how Git works. Once you clone a repo, you can do whatever you want with it. Permissions on the Azure DevOps side may prevent you from pushing your branch, but it won't stop you from creating and working on it.
If you accidentally do work on the wrong branch, you can merge or cherry-pick your commits to the correct branch later on.

In the Azure DevOps portal you can configure the permissions for each user or group.
Go to Project Settings > Repositories > All Repositories > [click on repo] > Security:


How will that prevent someone from creating a local branch off of the wrong branch and then doing work on it?
